# Oracle String functions to replace with an escape character?

Tags: string, oracle

How to achieve the following?

Original string:  `ERP Systems.Senior Application Analyst`

Replaced one/Intended output: `ERP Systems/.Senior Application Analyst`

How to escape the `.` with `/.` ?

```
 Begin
       REPLACE('ERP Systems.Senior Application Analyst', );
    end;
```

Comment: Something like `select REPLACE('ERP Systems.Senior Application Analyst', '.', '/.' ) from dual;` ?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)